# Case Insensitive search in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want to perform a hibernate named query but its giving hibernate syntax exception. In SQL it's running properly..chart will come as a query parameter and query value = `'chart'`?

```
SELECT * FROM faq WHERE UPPER(answer) LIKE UPPER('%chart%')

select f from Faq f where lower(f.question) like lower('%:query%') or lower(f.answer) like lower('%:query%')

@NamedQuery(name = "findQuesAnsByQuery", query = "select f from Faq f where lower(f.question) like lower('%:query%') or lower(f.answer) like lower('%:query%')")
```

Trace:

```
[0] = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@16677}"org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)"
[1] = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@16678}"org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)"
[2] = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@16679}"org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)"
[3] = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@16680}"org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)"
[4] = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@16681}"org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery(HibernateTemplate.java:979)"
[5] = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@16682}"org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery(HibernateTemplate.java:971)"
[6] = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@16683}"com.hk.impl.dao.BaseDaoImpl.findByNamedQuery(BaseDaoImpl.java:157)"
```

Comment: attache the stack trace please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in using the '%:query%'.. in the query.. Change to this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findQuesAnsByQuery"
  , query = "select f from Faq f 
        where lower(f.question) like lower(CONCAT('%', :query, '%')) 
           or lower(f.answer) like lower(CONCAT('%', :query, '%'))")
```

or

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findQuesAnsByQuery"
      , query = "select f from Faq f 
            where lower(f.question) like lower(:query) 
               or lower(f.answer) like lower(:query)")
```

and then set the param:

```
.setString("query", "%" + query+ "%")
```

Comment: Ok can you add the transactional method from which you invoke that query?

Comment: Also, add the Faq entity declaration

Comment: Its because the syntax issue by applying concat directly to the code not in hibernate query it worked fine

Comment: I see. Glad it helped you out